# how to group categorical values as a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, categorical-data

I have a [adult](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult) dataset that has a country column that has 41 different countries. To calculate accuracy, I have to convert categorical values into one hot encoder format which increases dimensionality. Here, in pandas, I want to group some countries to reduce dimensionality. For example, for {Columbia Ecuador Peru} I want to represent it as a new group named as {South-America}. Is there any pandas function to provide it?

Comment: Create a mapping for group to countries and create a new column on group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary to `Series` method `map()` directly:

```
mapping
{'columbia': 'south america', 'peru': 'south america', 'usa': 'north america', 'ecuador': 'south america', 'canada': 'north america'}

df
    country  value
0      peru      1
1  columbia      5
2   ecuador      6
3       usa      4
4    canada      3

df['country_mapped'] = df.country.map(mapping)

df
    country  value country_mapped
0      peru      1  south america
1  columbia      5  south america
2   ecuador      6  south america
3       usa      4  north america
4    canada      3  north america
```

Comment: Here, how can I merge two subgroup. I want to also merge some subgroup as new group. For example, america is a new group that contains {south-america, north-america}. Is it also possible?

Comment: You can do it the same way as the above by passing `country_mapped` to `map()` and using a separate dictionary describing the new group. Sample output would be helpful to understand your end-goal.. there's probably a better way.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't require a default value then just pass a dictionary to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
mapping = {
        'Columbia':'South-America',
        'Ecuador':'South-America',
        'Peru':'South-America',
        'South-Africa':'Africa',
        'Namibia':'Africa',
    }

df['country'].replace(mapping)
```

If you want a default then create a mapping function:

```
def group_countries(country):

    mapping = {
        'Columbia':'South-America',
        'Ecuador':'South-America',
        'Peru':'South-America',
        'South-Africa':'Africa',
        'Namibia':'Africa',
    }

    try:
        return mapping[country]
    except:
        return country
```

Apply it to your country column:

```
df['country_groups'] = df['country'].apply(group_countries)
```